# Bep20 liquidity locking(liquidity pool)

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

I want to create a liquidity lock (liquidity pool) what should I do?

(I just started so I used ready made code)

```
  pragma solidity ^0.8.2;

contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 10000 * 10 ** 18;
    string public name = "My Token";
    string public symbol = "TKN";
    uint public decimals = 18;
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    
    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }
    
    function balanceOf(address owner) public returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender) >= value, 'balance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
       emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'balance too low');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;   
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns (bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to make a fungible token. There is a standard for fungible tokens in EVM based blockchains and it is called ERC20, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol).

If you want to make a ERC20 token, you can use the contract like [this link](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/mocks/ERC20Mock.sol). Just need to change the name and the symbol of the token you want to create. You also might want to make changes to the mock contract, where you only allow the owner to mint and burn tokens. Which depends on how you want your contract to be.

Afterwards, just deploy your contract on-chain!